MariaDB SELECT only user cannot connect
I have created a SELECT-only login for a MariaDB database hosted on AWS RDS, named data with a password, and permission to connect from any host. The login should be able to connect to the server and SELECT only from all tables & views in a database named erp. The login should also be able to read view definitions.
Running show grants for 'data'@'%'; gives:
"GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `data`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*^^^^^'"
"GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON `erp`.* TO `data`@`%`"

Running
select user, host, password
from mysql.user
where user = 'data';

gives
"User","Host","Password"
"data","%","*^^^^"

However, when I try to connect using this login I get :
[28000][1045] (conn=3269827) Access denied for user 'data'@'^^^^' (using password: YES)

Any ideas - have I missed a step? Where should I look to try to troubleshoot this?

Password issue. Re-setting the password has allowed me to connect. There must have been an error in the original command to create the login so that the password was not the intended string (and it did only contain numbers & letters, I've been stung by MySQL handling of special characters in the past).
Edit: I am not deleting this question in the hope it might be useful for others as a reminder to make password checks a first step before asking for help on SO in future when faced with this access denied error.
